# Link to plugin list with filter

Tags: plugin

I'm building a simple Joomla plugin, and once installed, I want the description to contain a link to the plugin manager to make it easier to find and enable the plugin. At the moment I have something like this:

`<a href="index.php?option=com_plugins">Enable the plugin</a>`

Can I add any parameters to the URL to filter the results (and show only my own plugin), instead of having a list of all available plugins?

`<a href="index.php?option=com_plugins&search=myplugin">Enable the plugin</a>`

(this doesn't work, but maybe something similar?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this on v3.3 and it worked:

`index.php?option=com_plugins&view=plugins&filter_search=myplugin`

Comment: That's the one, knew it has `filter` in it, and turned out to be `filter_search`. +1

Comment: Perfect, that's the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: However this is the legacy way of doing filters. In J3.3. You now need to use the terminology

**index.php?option=com_plugins&filter[search]=myplugin** otherwise it can cause issues when you clear the filter and try to use another one